# Was bedeutet "der" in diesem Zusammenhang?

Tags: grammar

> Ich grub meiner Liebe ein grünes Grab, ich senkte sie in die Farne hinab. 2 Falken flogen droben her und einer `der` traf den anderen schwer und rote Tropfen fielen.

Ich dachte, dass `der eine` the one sei, aber in diesem Song sagt er `einer  der traf`. Ist das eine Art und Weise, wie man `der eine Falke traf den anderen` sagt?

Comment: Ich finde das "einer der" unbeholfen, ungeschickt, um nicht zu sagen unsauber konstruiert. Das "der" ist nur reingeflickt, weil es wie "schwer" den Hauptton trägt und sich mit "schwer" reimt.

Comment: Es könnte aber auch sein, dass hier ein Komma fehlt, was bei älteren Texten schon mal vorkommt: und einer (der beiden), der traf den andern schwer. Ohne "der" wäre der Sinn genau so, aber durch die Wiederaufname mit "der" entsteht nach "einer" eine Pause und dadurch eine stärkere Hervorhebung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Verständnis wird durch das Fehlen von Interpunktion erschwert. Ich hatte zuerst „einer der“ als Variante (die ich zumindest in modernem Deutsch nicht für korrekt gehalten hätte) von „einer dieser“ oder „einer ihrer“ gehalten. Tatsächlich ist der Satz aber wie folgt zu lesen.

> Zwei Falken flogen droben her, und einer, der traf den anderen schwer, und rote Tropfen fielen.

Das „der“ wiederholt hier nur das Subjekt „einer“. Es hätte ebenso gut weggelassen werden können, ohne den Inhalt zu ändern:

> Zwei Falken flogen droben her, und einer traf den anderen schwer, und rote Tropfen fielen.

In dem Lied von Faun höre ich übrigens:

> Zwei Falken flogen droben her. Der eine, der traf den andern gar schwer. Und rote Tropfen fielen.

Answer (score 2):

Diese Konstruktion ist poetisch und sehr ungewöhnlich, aber möglich. Normalerweise hieße es:

> Zwei Falken flogen droben her und einer *von ihnen* traf den anderen schwer und rote Tropfen fielen.

"der" bezieht sich also auf einen der beiden Falken. Direkt übersetzen kann man das nicht, da man im Englischen zwangsläufig "one of them" sagen muss.

Comment: Wäre auch "einer ihrer" richtig?

Comment: Müsste es in diesem Fall nicht eher "derer" heißen?