# How to modify "einer" in "einer von ihnen"

Tags: word-usage, pronoun

In a previous post [" How to say “one of them”? "](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17821/how-to-say-one-of-them)  there was a discussion on the difference between *einer von ihnen* and *einer davon*.  My question focuses on the *einer / eine / eines* and what gender to use for various groups of "them".

So, in the nominative case (to keep things simple?) and to say "One of them is missing", my assumptions are:

1. For a group with all the same gender, *ein* takes on the gender of the group
2. For mixed groups the priority is feminine, masculine, neutrum

**Scenario 1:  Groups with the same gender**

1.1  All women :  *Eine von ihnen fehlt.* -- Feminine

1.2  All men:  *Ein**_** von ihnen fehlt.* -- Masculine

1.3  All children:  *Ein**_** von ihnen fehlt.*  -- Neutrum

**Scenario 2:  Groups with mixed gender**

2.1  Women + men:  *Ein**e** von ihnen fehlt.*  -- Feminine

2.2  Men + children:  *Ein**_** von ihnen fehlt.* -- Masculine

2.3  Children + women: *Ein**e** von ihnen fehlt.*  -- Feminine

2.4  Women + men + children: *Ein**e** von ihnen fehlt.*  -- Feminine

I have not mixed the group with animals or inanimate objects.  I hope it doesn't make a difference.  After this, I don't think I will ever be a tour guide.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think there is a priority in mixed groups?

Your scenario 1 is fine: 

masculine - einer

feminine - eine

neutrum -eines

For mixed groups where the gender of the missing person is irrelevant, it's always masculine. Even if only women and children are present. (And no, we won't go into any discussion of equal rights or chivalry here.)

-> If you deviate from this, you are explicitly stating that a person of gender x is missing.

Comment: Originally, I could not work what the rules were so I guessed there might be some prioritisation.  Your guidance makes it very clear. Thanks!