# How to say “one of them” in German?

Tags: pronoun

I think I am right in saying that *denen* would be used to mean *them*, but what ending would be used for the *one*, because there is no obvious gender?

> Einer von denen
>   Eines von denen
>   Eine von denen

For example “One of them is tired”, with *them* being a group of random people? Or “He is one of them”, with *them* again being a group of random people?

Like I said, I don’t know which of the three genders would be used here, and also in general usage of *einer* as an indefinite pronoun.

Comment: who are the "them"?

Comment: Does that make a difference? I will edit question with context though.

Comment: yes, that's what decides which to use

Comment: Funny enough, when I changed the title from single quotation marks to double quotation marks, I got an error saying: "This title is already in use." -> http://german.stackexchange.com/q/17821/1224. It's not a dupe though, I guess. — And besides, I don't understand your very last sentence. What are you asking there?

Comment: That is only tangential to your question, but in many contexts, "einer von ihnen" would be more natural. "Denen" is more like "those".

Comment: @CarstenS; I fully agree with the statement, but considering the headline of the question it seems definitely relevant.

Answer (score 6):

1. The simple way to decide is to think that there is a word in your sentence which you left out. If it is an inanimate object, use the gender of the word which is missing.

   > a) Ein Messer von den Messern → Eins von denen
   >
   > b) Ein Löffel von den Löffeln → Einer von denen
   >
   > c) Eine Gabel von den Gabeln → Eine von denen

   As pointed out in the comments, *denen* is colloquial, use *von ihnen* in a more official context.
2. When it comes to entities which have their own “non-grammatical” gender, you use the gender of the entity you are referring to.

   > a) Ein Arzt von den Ärzten und Ärztinnen → Einer von denen
   >
   > b) Eine Ärztin von den Ärzten und Ärztinnen → Eine von denen

   If you don’t mean to refer to one specific entity of the group, but mean *any of them,* use the generic singular genus for that group.

   > c) Irgendein Arzt oder irgendeine Ärztin von den Ärtzen und Ärztinnen → Einer von denen
   >
   > d) Irgendein Kater oder irgendeine Katze von den Katern und Katzen → Eine von denen
3. If you need to emphasize political correctness when referring to humans, you could use *oder*. This makes it quite clumsy, and is unlikely to be found outside of the writings of organisations who actively promote gender equality.

   > Irgendein Arzt oder irgendeine Ärztin von den Ärzten und Ärztinnen → Einer oder eine von ihnen

Choosing an unexpected reference group might be grammatically correct, but it is likely to be misunderstood.

> Irgendeine Person von den Personen → Eine von denen → Eine Frau von den Frauen und Männern

If you haven’t introduced the word *Person* recently in the conversation, your conversation partner will automatically assume that you are talking about case 2, with the group consisting of “Frauen und Männer”. And because 2a) and 2c) both result in the choice of the male gender, he’ll think that this is case 2b), a specific female human, not 2c), a random person of any gender.

**Update** After reading [user unknown's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26536/5297), I realized that there is a case I forgot to describe. Added here for completeness.

4. If in the flow of conversation, you previously referred to the group with a plural substantive describing the role of its elements, use the gender of this substantive in singular. This applies to both animate and inanimate entities. The requirement is that the substantive itself does not change gender depending on the role.

> a) You get asked "War es eins von den Utensilien da?" . The answer is:
>
> Ein Utensil von den Utensilien → "Ja, eins von denen"

You use the gender of `Utensil` even though each individual fork would require `die` and each individual spoon would require `der`.

> b) The regulations of a political party might state "Eine Kommission muss aus mindestens vier Parteimitgliedern bestehen." The next sentence says that they need to designate a chairperson.
>
> Ein Mitglied von den Mitgliedern → "Eins von ihnen muss zum Vorsitzenden ernannt werden."

Even though all the members of the committee are men and women, you use the gender of "Mitglied", which is neuter.

If a substantive is already introduced, but it changes gender depending on the role (Arzt/Ärztin, Vorsitzender/Vorsitzende), use rule 2.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that the gender could be more than one? Like Mensch is masculine, but Person is feminine?

Comment: @JacobLee-Hart it probably can produce cases where two choices are right. But in your example, it would be strange. Nobody is accustomed to think of "Menschen" as "Personen" in everyday speech, just like in English you say "one of the people" but not "one of the persons". So if you refer to a random human who is part of a crowd as "Eine von denen", nobody will get your reference to "one person from that group of persons", your communication partner will think you mean "one woman from that group of people".

Answer (score 3):

Das zu benutzende Geschlecht ergibt sich aus dem Geschlecht, von dem zuvor die Rede sein musste:

> In meiner Straße gibt es drei Bäcker. **Einer von denen** backt noch selbst.
>   (Der Bäcker, mask.)
>
> In meinem Verein gibt es vier Mitglieder. **Eines von denen** ist vom Mitgliedsbeitrag befreit.
>   (Das Mitglied, sächl.)
>
> 17 Personen standen im Aufzug. **Eine von denen** hatte starken Mundgeruch. 
>   (Die Person, fem.)

Man ist an das sprachliche Geschlecht gebunden, welches man zuvor verwendet hat um die Gruppe zu beschreiben.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the other answers, you *should* (if possible) use the genus of whatever you are referring to. User unknown did a nice comparison between what happens if you use *Bäcker, Mitglieder* or *Personen* (which are masculine, feminine and neuter words, respectively).

As rumtscho said, if you are just referring to *any random person* and the specifics of that person do not matter at all, you would use the word’s genus, too. For people, this defaults to masculine:

> Einer von denen da drüben wird gleich eine Rede halten.

For *specific* animals, it defaults to whatever their genus is:

> Eine von denen *points at cats* hat mich gekratzt!

And for a mixed or *generic* group of animals, it defaults to neuter (cf. *das Tier*):

> Eines von denen (*Tieren auf dem Bauernhof*) werden wir morgen essen.

For objects, it defaults to neuter, too (cf. *das Ding*):

> *points to a pile of objects* Eines von denen werde ich brauchen.

Comment: Wenn zuvor die Gruppe nicht benannt wurde, dann ergibt sich nicht automatisch ein Geschlecht, denn viele Elemente lassen sich in unterschiedlich benannten Gruppen mit divergierendem Geschlecht zusammenfassen. Das Objekt, das Ding, aber der Gegenstand oder die Sache.